# Moisture in the bathroom is bubbling lead paint - how do I seal it?

Tags: bathroom, paint, plaster, sealing, lead

I live in a home built in the 1930s. The bathroom has been poorly remodeled at least twice. At the last remodel, before I moved in, the work wasn't finished. Within the shower everything is fine, but the paint on the arched wall on the shower/tub's exterior, which was left exposed at the last remodel, is bubbling away because of moisture. I've recently tested this area and found that it has traces of lead.

[image: Wall - Bubbling Paint]

I am looking for a solution to seal the exposed section of wall without disturbing the lead paint. I don't have a true HEPA shopvac, which I feel prevents me from dealing with the lead paint and taking this wall down to the surface and starting from scratch. I won't be living in this home more than another year and I don't have a lot of experience doing DIY work. Would using a sealer like Zinsser Gardz work? The aesthetics of the fix don't matter - my only concern is preventing further disturbance or pulverization of the lead paint.

There is a section of this wall that is covered in broken plaster. Would finishing up the wall with some type of plaster repair compound do the trick?

[image: Broken plaster]

I'm looking for solutions that I could implement myself. If this isn't possible and this is a problem a professional should tackle, I will take that under consideration.

Answer (score 1):

I was researching exactly the same thing and came across a few products that does not require you to scrape the paint off.

[EcoBond](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01CF55DJU) - you paint the surface and it will react with the lead.